# Openshift node.js successful deployment, but "Application is not available"

Tags: node.js, openshift

I'm having a problem getting a node.js app to run on Openshift.

I've set up my openshift project to pull from a git repo.

My `server.listen` call is being made like this:

```
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || process.env.PORT || 8080;
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';

var server = http.createServer(myServerFunction);
server.listen(port, ip);
```

The pull and build work fine. I can see in the pod terminal that my app is running because there is some `console.log` output indicating this. I can also see that neither `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` nor `process.env.IP` exist, and so the port has defaulted to `8080`.

If I go into the pod's terminal and execute `curl http://localhost:8080` I see precisely the html output I would expect from my app.

However, when I click on the overview tab and find the external url for my app (which is of the format `http://<application>-<domain>.1d35.starter-us-east-1.openshiftapps.com`), clicking that link results in openshift's "Application is not available" error page.

It seems to me that my node app is running perfectly well, but is not connected to the external url. I suspect that `8080` is not the correct port, and that I am required to do more configuration in order for my nodejs app to receive a value at `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT`.

In other stackoverflow answers I've also seen `0.0.0.0` as the default when `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP` is not set. Could this make a difference?

**Overall, how can I make the external url link to my nodejs server?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You must use 0.0.0.0 not 127.0.0.1 or it will not accept connection requests from outside of the pod.

Comment: I've switched over to port 0.0.0.0, that's gotten things working!! If you put down an answer I'll give you the check. Also a link to the documentation where `0.0.0.0` is recommended as a default ip, or an explanation why that particular ip will work instead of `localhost` would probably be great for other people like me! :)

Comment: Some very brief notes on what settings you should use is given at https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/migrating_applications/web_framework_applications.html#dev-guide-migrating-web-framework-applications-node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to
Applications > Services,
click on your service,
click Actions > Edit YAML,
In ports sections,
change port and targetPort to the port that your nodejs application is running on,
in my case it was on port 8000,
so i gave like this

```
port: 8000
protocol: TCP
targetPort: 8000
```

Also, check that app is running on "0.0.0.0", not "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing an application using Red Hat Developer Sandbox. I had the same error message page when trying to access the endpoint indicated by Openshift console.

The issue on my side was that the Ingress rule was missing.

I fixed it switching to the admin view, then neworking, and ingress. There I just changed  service name, port and path to match my service, and host to match what openshift has created for me. That worked