# OpenShift Online 3 Application is not available right after deploy

Tags: openshift

Each time I make a deploy of my application with OpenShift Online 3, when I visit the actual URL of the application, I get the "Application is not available" page.

This page keeps being returned for some minutes after the deploy, and then all of a sudden the application works again.

I've seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267689/openshift-node-js-successful-deployment-but-application-is-not-available) that this might be due to incorrect IP configuration of the application server, but in my case it's a simple PHP application over Apache (built upon the basic PHP catalog framework chosen during the OpenShift application creation), so I never got to configure the server parameters.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openshift/bP2las-Wfbw) it's suggested that pods might be crashing and being re-created, so I checked with `oc get pods --watch`, but didn't see any error, just what it seems to be regular pods creation and termination. Even after the new pod is marked as `Running`, with the `READY` field set to `1/1`, I still keep seeing the "Application is not available" page.

Events and logs on the OpenShift dashboard don't seem to report any problem either.

Does anybody know what could be the problem here?

Comment: Some of the OpenShift Online Starter clusters are currently experiencing issues with delay propagation of routes as part of application creation and deployment issues. The issue is being investigated. You can see status for any OpenShift Online Starter clusters at https://status.starter.openshift.com/

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was a problem with my configuration. I'll wait for it to be fixed then.