# Openshift: any deployment resulted in Application is not available

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin, minishift

Fist time deploying to OpenShift (actually minishift in my Windows 10 Pro). Any sample application I deploied successfully resulted in:

[image]

From Web Console I see a weird message "Build #1 is pending" although I saw it was successfully from PowerShell

[image]

I found someone fixing similiar issue changing to 0.0.0.0 ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46267689/4148175)) but I give a try and it isn't the solution in my case.

Here are the full logs and how I am deploying

```
PS C:\to_learn\docker-compose-to-minishift\first-try>  oc new-app https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex                warning: Cannot check if git requires authentication.
--> Found image 93de123 (16 months old) in image stream "openshift/nodejs" under tag "10" for "nodejs"

    Node.js 10.12.0
    ---------------
    Node.js  available as docker container is a base platform for building and running various Node.js  applications and frameworks. Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

    Tags: builder, nodejs, nodejs-10.12.0

    * The source repository appears to match: nodejs
    * A source build using source code from https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex will be created
      * The resulting image will be pushed to image stream tag "nodejs-ex:latest"
      * Use 'start-build' to trigger a new build
      * WARNING: this source repository may require credentials.
                 Create a secret with your git credentials and use 'set build-secret' to assign it to the build config.
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "nodejs-ex"
    * Port 8080/tcp will be load balanced by service "nodejs-ex"
      * Other containers can access this service through the hostname "nodejs-ex"

--> Creating resources ...
    imagestream.image.openshift.io "nodejs-ex" created
    buildconfig.build.openshift.io "nodejs-ex" created
    deploymentconfig.apps.openshift.io "nodejs-ex" created
    service "nodejs-ex" created
--> Success
    Build scheduled, use 'oc logs -f bc/nodejs-ex' to track its progress.
    Application is not exposed. You can expose services to the outside world by executing one or more of the commands below:
     'oc expose svc/nodejs-ex'
    Run 'oc status' to view your app.
PS C:\to_learn\docker-compose-to-minishift\first-try>  oc get bc/nodejs-ex -o yaml                                      apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/generated-by: OpenShiftNewApp
  creationTimestamp: 2020-02-20T20:10:38Z
  labels:
    app: nodejs-ex
  name: nodejs-ex
  namespace: samplepipeline
  resourceVersion: "1123211"
  selfLink: /apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/samplepipeline/buildconfigs/nodejs-ex
  uid: 1003675e-541d-11ea-9577-080027aefe4e
spec:
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: nodejs-ex:latest
  postCommit: {}
  resources: {}
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    git:
      uri: https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex
    type: Git
  strategy:
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        name: nodejs:10
        namespace: openshift
    type: Source
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  triggers:
  - github:
      secret: c3FoC0RRfTy_76WEOTNg
    type: GitHub
  - generic:
      secret: vlKqJQ3ZBxfP4HWce_Oz
    type: Generic
  - type: ConfigChange
  - imageChange:
      lastTriggeredImageID: 172.30.1.1:5000/openshift/nodejs@sha256:3cc041334eef8d5853078a0190e46a2998a70ad98320db512968f1de0561705e
    type: ImageChange
status:
  lastVersion: 1
```

Comment: You should start with checking pods state: oc get pod. If build or other application pods in pending status, check it's events via 'oc describe pod PODNAME' and logs via 'oc logs PODNAME'. Also you can check events via 'oc get events'